# Firewall Blocking web deploy

Tags: web-services, iis, web-deployment, webdeploy

I am trying to deploy a web service to my server which is running IIS8 with Web Deploy installed. Using visual studio I am able to successfully deploy the web service when the firewall is disabled but not when it is enabled.

I have created Firewall rules to allow inbound and outbound on port 8172 but this still has not resolved the issue. Could anyone suggest a solution that does not involve disabling my firewall on my server?

Answer (score 1):

Run a network sniffer like Wireshark to see what is being blocked when the firewall is on.  There may be other ports that are required.

Answer (score 0):

you can open;

- BranchCache - Hosted Cache client
- BranchCache - Hosted Cache server